# How to add setTimeout function for the Foreach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Hi want to set the timeout funtion for the Freach loop for the callback i am setting the timeout funtion. but its displaying Undifined error. can anybody Explain me here is My code.

```js
function async(array,cb){

    array.forEach(function () {
        setTimeout(cb,0);

    })

}

async([1,2,3,4],function(i){
    console.log(i);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```js
function async(array,cb){
    array.forEach(function(e) {
        setTimeout(function() { cb(e); },0);

    });
}

async([1,2,3,4,5], function(i) {
  console.log(i);
});
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks its Working, can you please explain me what the error in my code.

Comment: @Jeevan You need to pass the argument from forEach to your function, to do so you need to wrap that function with anonymous function and call your function with argument from forEach.